# AdMob Interstitial and error isLoaded must be called on the main UI thread

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

After user William suggest me to change my code for showing interstitial ad to this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    //setDebugMode(true);
    initialiseAccelerometer();

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id));

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Create another ad request.
            final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    });
    // Create ad request.
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

and for showing ad this:

```
public synchronized void GameOver() {
    if (lives_left > 0) {
        //success! - game passed - save score
        ScoreManager.save_localscore_simple(score_times[currentLevel], "" + currentLevel, false);

        if (Level_Buttons.length >= currentLevel + 1)
            ScoreManager.save_localscore_simple(unlocked, "unlock" + (currentLevel + 1));

        if (sound_success != 0 && !sound_muted)
            sp.play(sound_success, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

        //open interstitial ad
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }


    } else {
        //game not passed
        if (sound_gameover != 0 && !sound_muted)
            sp.play(sound_gameover, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }


    //open interstitial ad
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }

    StopMusic();
    state = GAMEOVER;

}
```

On every gameover in game I get this error:

```
W/dalvikvm(20469): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception      (group=0x4180bda0)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-67543
E/AndroidRuntime(20469): Process: com.test.mygame, PID: 20469
E/AndroidRuntime(20469): java.lang.IllegalStateException: isLoaded must be      called on the main UI thread.
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at     com.google.android.gms.common.internal.bh.b(SourceFile:251)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at  com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.b.e(SourceFile:345)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.m.onTransact(SourceFile:66)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ap$a$a.isReady(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.isLoaded(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.isLoaded(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at com.test.mygame.MainGame.GameOver(MainGame.java:1128)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at com.test.mygame.MainGame.Step(MainGame.java:773)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at com.test.nudge.Screen.run(Screen.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(20469):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

What is wrong here? Please explain me simple as possible because I`m newbie without any programming knowledge before :) Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is maybe not the full answer, but It´s hard to say the right answer because it´s not clear from Your code above. You´ve not showed where You use GameOver(), but I think You called it in the wrong place, I think You call it in any background thread because inside GameOver You call `interstitial.isLoaded()` which causing Your problem. Like the stacktrace said, call it in the main ui thread. For exqample, call this inside Your GameOver():

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
              interstitial.show();
         }
        }
    });
```

Possibly You have to call it with an activity reference, it depends from where Do You call GameOver():

```
    mYourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
              interstitial.show();
         }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh, works like a charm! :) You made my day, because I was looking for solution for to remove Interstitial delay for about 2 weeks now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Share my case and solution.

I did new thread and call isLoaded(). It got this same error. 
So that I solve it by below code using Messager.

Hope this help.

Code as below.

Main thread:

```
public void onCreate() {

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                switch (message.what) {
                    case ACTION_ADMOB_IS_LOADED:
                        MainActivity.logForDebug(TAG,"AdMob : Check for loaded");
                        if(mIAds.isLoaded()) {
                            MainActivity.logForDebug(TAG,"AdMob : Loaded ...... OK");
                            mIAds.show();
                        }
                        break;
                }


            }
        };

}
```

Other thread

```
    public void run(){

        while(true){
                Message message;
                // ------  For AdMob ------
                Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(ACTION_ADMOB_IS_LOADED,null);
                message.sendToTarget();
                   }
        }
```